# How to apply event handling on multiple elements with onmouseover and onmouseout

Tags: javascript

With ES6 arrow functions, I am trying to apply a hover state on any of several anchor links that share the same class name.  But the following only works when I hover over the first element, but not the rest. What I am missing from this logic?

The HTML:

```
 <nav id="demo-links">
   <a href="/" class="mlink">Link A</a>
   <a href="/" class="mlink">Link B</a>
   <a href="/" class="mlink">Link C</a>
   <a href="/" class="mlink">Link D</a>
 </nav>
```

The JavaScript:

```
let mItem = document.querySelector(".mlink");
mItem.onmouseover = () => mItem.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
mItem.onmouseout = () => mItem.removeAttribute("target");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event works for the first element because

> The Document method [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) returns the first Element within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors. If no matches are found, null is returned.

Use [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) instead.

> The Element method [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a static (not live) NodeList representing a list of the document's elements that match the specified group of selectors.

You can use `forEach()` to loop through all the `li`'s to set the event individually:

```js
let mItem = document.querySelectorAll(".mlink");
mItem.forEach(function(el){
  el.onmouseover = () => el.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
  el.onmouseout = () => el.removeAttribute("target");
});
```

```html
<nav id="demo-links">
   <a href="/" class="mlink">Link A</a>
   <a href="/" class="mlink">Link B</a>
   <a href="/" class="mlink">Link C</a>
   <a href="/" class="mlink">Link D</a>
</nav>
```